# Use Case diagrams as a requirements gathering tool for new functionality - particularly in systems that only require very little user interaction

Tags: requirements, use-case, real-time-systems

I'm interested in persuing the idea of using Use Case Diagrams as a tool for collecting user requirements.  However, it will be for new features as opposed to developing a system from scratch.  Also, the system only has a small level of user interaction - most of the actors will be external systems.

I want to know what people's experiances have been with using this method of gathering requirements.  How did your customers respond to the change and was it positive?  Did it just not work for anybody?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main benefits of use-cases is they help communicate ideas clearly, so that you and end-users can get on the same wavelength.  They can provoke discussion and reveal subtleties that users (or you) might take for granted.

On the other hand interaction between systems is concrete, so you can dispense with discussion and instead seek to document hard facts; what data will be transmitted, what volumes, what form will it take, what happens when garbage is received, and so on.

Comment: +1 In the second half are you saying that it is better to document facts than to use Use Case diagrams?

Comment: Now I'm not saying Use Cases diagrams are lies :-)  Rather, system interaction is sufficiently concrete that you will get little extra benefit from use-case diagrams, unless you need to talk about the interaction at a high-level (in which case a whiteboard would do as well)

Comment: @Ed That's a very good point - I don't want to fall into the trap of using a methodology just because I want to use it (regardless if its appropriate or not)